# count the frequency of elements in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Say, I have the following sorted list of lists :

List 1  : (12,24,36)

List 2  : (3,5,12,24)

List 3  : (36,41,69)

I want to find out the frequency of each element in the entire list of lists. I came up with an ugly module for the same in python but I was wondering if there is some library function..

Edit : Please find the code below

```
def find_frequency(transactions,list):
    freq = 0
    for items_transaction in transactions:
        flag = 0
        for candidate in list:
            if candidate not in items_transaction:
                flag = 1
                break
        if flag == 0:
            freq += 1
    return freq
```

Comment: What is the code that you came up with? Please show your efforts first.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name - it's a type name.

Comment: You should probably accept the answer by @AChampion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Counter does what I believe you are looking for:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list1, list2, list3 = [12,24,36], [3,5,12,24], [36,41,69]
>>> Counter(chain(list1, list2, list3))
Counter({3: 1, 5: 1, 12: 2, 24: 2, 36: 2, 41: 1, 69: 1})
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who searched by the title referring to list of lists, it seems like a simple solution is:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
list_of_lists = [[12,24,36], [3,5,12,24], [36,41,69]]
Counter(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to flatten a list - that is, transform it to a single long sequence of all values. It can be done using [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
import collections, itertools
l = [[12,24,36], [3,5,12,24], [36,41,69]]
freq = collections.defaultdict(int)  # 0 by default
for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l):
    freq[x] += 1
print(freq)
```

Comment: If you are going to use `collections`, you may as well use `Counter` :)

Comment: @AChampion You out-pythoned me, I'm upvoting your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the list using what some other posters have said, and then do something like this.

```
def numList(list):
        dic = {}
        for num in list:
            if num in dic.keys():
                dic[num] += 1
            else:       
                key = num
                value = 1
                dic[key] = value
        return dic
```

This creates a dictionary of all the numbers in a list and their frequencies.  The dictionary key is the number, and its value is the frequency.